# Double Integral Equations

Tags: real-analysis, calculus-of-variations

In my research I've come across a handful of double integral equations, and I'm nearly at a total loss for how to derive anything useful from such things.

I've been lead to believe that even single integral equations are quite difficult to handle, so I would imagine problems escalate considerably when considering double integral equations.

That being said, the most compelling equation I've derived is
$$
0=\int_0^\ell\int_0^\ell f(s,t)\mu(t)\mu^\prime(s)\,ds\,dt;
$$
where I'm attempting to solve for $\mu$.

The particular $f$ I'm dealing with has a variety of nice properties: $\ell$-periodic, nonnegative, symmetric, continuous.  The $\mu$ I'm looking for will be those that are $\ell$-periodic, positive, and continuous.  For the sake of this discussion you may assume $f$ and $\mu$ have any properties that you desire them to have.

Ultimately, the question is this: what information can I gather from the above statements?  It would be incredible if there was some way to solve for solutions, but I doubt such a method exists.  Obviously any constant $\mu$ will be a solution, but I'm trying to find other results.

Any advice or relevant references are highly appreciated.

Comment: Isnt $\mu'$ supposed to be $\mu$?

Comment: I suspect it's supposed to be the derivative of $\mu$, otherwise constant $\mu$ wouldn't be "obviously" a solution.

Comment: Yes, $\mu^\prime$ is indeed correct.  For context, this equation arose in an attempt to use calculus of variations.

Answer (score 2):

Take some nice "trial functions" $\mu_j(t)$, and consider the $d$-parameter family $\mu_\lambda(t) = \sum_{j=1}^d \lambda_j \mu_j(t)$.  The right side 
of your equation is a quadratic form in $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_d$.  If it doesn't happen to be positive definite or negative definite, you can solve the quadratic form and get nontrivial solutions.